# Why phpBB template not registering this var in search.php?

Tags: phpbb, phpbb3

I have this in my search.php, outside any if's and functions, mostly at the root of the document

```
$template->assign_var('S_BUSCA_GP', true);
```

Still, when i come to the search_results.html and put {S_BUSCA_GP} it prints nothing, also, if i try  it treats the var as not existent or false, going out of the loop.

I'm pretty much lost right now... :/

__ EDIT __

This is where it is, still, i've tried it in many places on search.php and still i have nothing on the 'view', i already tried to assign a string also, i made plenty of test before coming to you guys ;(

```
$template->set_filenames(array(
    'body' => 'search_body.html')
);
$template->assign_vars(Array('S_BUSCA_GP' => true, 'LE_VAR_TEST' => 'Variável de Teste'));

make_jumpbox(append_sid("{$phpbb_root_path}viewforum.$phpEx"));
```

__ EDIT 2 __

Actually, even when i try adding a direct string into the template... it doen't work... where is the search results template in? I've encountering some problem findinf it... the one i'm editing is in

phpBB_ROOT/styles/subsilver2/template/search_results.html

Answer (score 2):

If you're just adding {S_BUSCA_GP} then yes it will print nothing as there is no output from the var. If you do somewthing like this:

```
$template->assign_var('S_BUSCA_GP', 'Hello World');
```

This will print 'Hello World' wherever you place the template var in your html file.

You're probably wanting to do something like this though:

```
<!-- IF S_BUSCA_GP -->
   S_BUSCA_GP is set to TRUE
<!-- ELSE -->
   S_BUSCA_GP is set to FALSE
<!-- ENDIF -->
```

As long as S_BUSCA_GP is set to true, it will show the true message. otherwise it will show the false message

*Edit*

Ok after looking at your edit, I think i see why. Your code is being placed near the bottom i think - as you mentioned search_body in your post. You'll probably want to target a bit further up. Try around line 1040, search for this code:

```
page_header(($l_search_title) ? $l_search_title : $user->lang['SEARCH']);

$template->set_filenames(array(
    'body' => 'search_results.html')
);
```

Comment: If for any reason that still isn't working, can you edit your post and add in 3 or 4 lines of code before and after where you placed your assign_var call in search.php

Comment: Have you tried clearing the template cache? You could try adding some random text to the html file (outside any if statements) and if it doesn't show, then you should clear the cache and check again

Comment: already did a few times, i just can't find the search template, in any of the styles... kinda lost ;(

Comment: Ok, I think I see now. Check the edit at the bottom of my answer. Try placing your code a little further up in search.php and then see if the HTML shows

Comment: Placed an print_r($_REQUEST) at the top, nothing on the 'view'.. :/